# using hebrew in powerdot/beamer

Tags: lyx, hebrew, ps2pdf, powerdot

I am trying to make a presentation in hebrew using lyx. I tryed beamer but it did not go well. Then I tryed powerdot, but when I compiled the document (ps2pdf) no hebrew was displayed (empty document). Does someone know how to solve the problem? or another way to create presentations in hebrew? The tool I want to use is lyx, and not latex editor. Thanks for helpers!

Here is the document I compiled (with ps2pdf) and I got an empty pdf file:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{powerdot}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{דג}\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Here is a file I compiled with ps2pdf:

```
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass powerdot
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding cp1255
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\paperwidth 5cm
\paperheight 5cm
\topmargin 2cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0bp
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
דג
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Here is a file I compiled with xetex:

```
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass beamer
\begin_preamble
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding cp1255
\fontencoding global
\font_roman Arial
\font_sans Arial
\font_typewriter Arial
\font_math default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 11
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\paperwidth 5cm
\paperheight 5cm
\topmargin 2cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0bp
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
דגכ סב
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a bit too vague, I'm afraid. Could you make a couple of short examples that fail?

Comment: updated. The problem is even in the most naive examples.

Comment: @Shlomi can you please post a .lyx file with your attempt? Can you compile the Hebrew example files that come with LyX? They all compile for me on Ubuntu with LyX 2.1.2. It's just a matter of getting the right fonts installed and recognized. What operating system do you use?

Comment: I can compile it and see the output in an ordinary file but not powerdot. I am using Windows 7. How can I post a file? Now I get another problem that I cannot see hebrew when I compile with xetex, even in an article. I think the problems are related

Comment: @Shlomi If you do not notify me with @ followed by my username, I will not know that you are responding to me (unless I happen to remember to check back). The .lyx file is just a text file. You can open it in a text editor and copy/paste.

Comment: @scottkosty I updated. thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: @Shlomi I cannot compile the files either. You might want to contact the powerdot mailing list. The author, Hendri, is very responsive. powerdot@freelists.org

Comment: @Shlomi if you do find a solution, please post it here (you can answer your own question)

Comment: @scottkosty I can compile the files but I do not see any hebrew characters. I will ask him. thanks!

Comment: It doen’t answer your question exactly (you said you want to use LyX), but have a look a this solution which uses LuaLaTeX+Babel+Beamer+Metropolis: [post](https://digitalwords.net/beamer-hebrew/), [presentation](https://digitalwords.net/media/beamer-hebrew/beamer-hebrew.pdf), [source](https://gitlab.com/rwmpelstilzchen/beamer-hebrew/blob/master/beamer-hebrew.tex).